# Spring-boot thymeleaf having problem with the @pahtvariable want to pull out a single record from database

Tags: java, html, mysql, spring-boot, thymeleaf

So my problem is that I want to pull out a single record form my database (mysql-workbench). So when you are on the homepage you can see all the records from the database, what I want is when you press the button "read more" on a record you go into a new html page depening on want record you chose to read more on an here want to pull a single record out by using the @pathvarable. Hope I makes sense.

So the problem I think must be in the controller with
@GetMapping ("/faellesskab/{faellesskabNavn}") and in the html file where I use it wrong.

So I have no problem in seeing all the records from the database, but when I want to pull out one I have the problem in the html file th:field="*{faellesskabNavn}.

```
@Controller
public class FaellesskabController {

    @Autowired
    FaellesskabServiceI fs;

    @Autowired
    BegivenhedServiceI bs;

    @GetMapping ("/faellesskaber")
    public String faellesskaberForm(Model model) throws Exception {
        model.addAttribute("faellesskablist",fs.getFaellesskabList());
        model.addAttribute("faellesskaber", new Faellesskab());

        return "faellesskaber";
    }


    @GetMapping ("/faellesskab/{faellesskabNavn}")
    public String faellesskabNavn(Model model, @PathVariable String faellesskabNavn) throws Exception {

            Faellesskab faellesskab = fs.getSingleFaelleskab(faellesskabNavn);
            System.out.println(faellesskab);
            model.addAttribute("faellesskabSingle",faellesskab);
            return "faellesskab";
    }


}
```

HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Fællesskaber</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-50">
        <h1 class="my-4">Velkommen til fællesskaberne</h1>

        <!-- Marketing Icons Section -->
        <div class="row">
            <!-- <form action th:action="@{faelleskab}" th:object="${faellesskabNavn}" method="get"> -->
            <div class="col-lg-4 mb-4" th:each="Faellesskaber : ${faellesskablist}">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <h4 class="card-header" th:text="${Faellesskaber.faellesskabNavn}"></h4>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text" th:text="${Faellesskaber.faellesskabBeskrivelse}"></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <a href="/faellesskab" class="btn btn-primary">Læs mere</a>
                        <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Beskrivelse"> -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="contentwrapper">
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/faellesskab}" th:object="${faellesskabSingle}" method="get">
        <p>Fællesskab navn: <input type="text" required="required" th:field="*{faellesskabNavn}"/></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>
    <br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Createpatient">Opret patient</button></td>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The error message I get. 
Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "faellesskaber" - line 38, col 68)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `th:field` try using th:value and add a name to it.

```
<p>Fællesskab navn: <input type="text" required="required" th:value="${faellesskabNavn}" name="faellesskabNavn" /></p>
```